# Need assistance with WPF Converter not functioning

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where I'm using a converter as a boolean to turn some text red if a time is displayed over the time frame specified. Times update every 3 seconds. when someone is marked being on break and they go on break for more then 15 minutes then the text displayed in the datagrid should turn red. In this case nothing happens and I can't find the problem.

Converter:

```
 public class BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime : IValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly TimeSpan _toCompare = new TimeSpan(00, 15, 00);
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value is TimeSpan))
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            return (TimeSpan)value > _toCompare;
        }       

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("To Long On Break");
        }        
    }
```

XAML Code:

```
 <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Binding="{Binding AuxReasons}" Value="Break"/>
  <Condition Binding="{Binding Time, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource breakconvtime}}" Value="True"/>                                
 </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: Did you defined a resource `BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime ` with the key `breakconvtime`?

Comment: yes that is defined. Sorry i forgot to include that in my code. The code compiles with no errors.

Comment: @firehotguitar88, debug it. set a breakpoint in Convert method to confirm that it called (or not), and that it receives and returns correct (or incorrect) values. Also in case if `Time` is a property of view model `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` isn't required.

Comment: Does my answer below help?

Comment: @ASh looks like the breaktolunchconverter is never being called. i tried to remove the relativesource but that made no difference in the fact that its not called.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how and WHERE you bind it, but maybe `RelativeSource` in not needed here.

The following works for me (I used `Prism`):

```
<Window x:Class="TimeBasedTrigger.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:TimeBasedTrigger.Converters"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    Width="525"
    Height="350"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:BreakRangeToBooleanConverterTime x:Key="breakconvtime" />
    <Style x:Key="TimeoutStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <!--<Condition Binding="{Binding AuxReasons}" Value="Break" />-->
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Time, Converter={StaticResource breakconvtime}}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Time: " />
        <TextBlock MinWidth="100"
                   Margin="5,0,10,0"
                   Text="{Binding Time, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Style="{StaticResource TimeoutStyle}" / >
        <Button Command="{Binding StartTimerCommand}" Content="Start" />
        <Button Command="{Binding StopTimerCommand}" Content="Stop" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Time = new TimeSpan();
    }

    #region Properties

    private string _title = "Prism Unity Application";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    private TimeSpan _time;
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _time, value); }
    }

    private bool _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return _isRunning; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isRunning, value); }
    }
    #endregion // Properties

    #region Commands

    public DelegateCommand StartTimerCommand => new DelegateCommand(StartTimer);

    private async void StartTimer()
    {
        await RepeatActionEvery(() => UpdateTimer(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), _cts.Token);
    }

    public DelegateCommand StopTimerCommand => new DelegateCommand(StopTimer);

    private void StopTimer()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        Time = new TimeSpan();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    #endregion // Commands

    #region Private Methods

    private void UpdateTimer()
    {
        var timeIncrement = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        Time = Time.Add(timeIncrement);
    }

    #endregion // Private Methods

    #region Helpers

    public static async Task RepeatActionEvery(Action action, TimeSpan interval, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            action();
            Task task = Task.Delay(interval, cancellationToken);

            try { await task; }
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { return; }
        }
    }

    #endregion // Helpers
}
```

Comment: i don't know what prism is. I'm very new to WPF and haven't been using the MVVM style in my application which i'm starting to believe was a mistake on my part.  also your view model above i don't understand its purpose. if i'm reading it right that is what you did to increment the time in the timer counting up correct? in my case the time i'm measuring is being reported from an interface so i need to look at a timespan already bound to a field in a datagrid to determine if the converter activates or not.

Comment: You're binding to Time property in your XAML, so this property has to raise  `PropertyChanged` in order to make the binding to work. What's your code for this? Is this in a code-behind file?

Comment: i don't currently do that. so its probably my issue. i've never had to bind a property changing value before, i thought the XAML just referenced the converter all the time.